# add_shortcode() not working inside of function

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I have a custom post type `bhour`, with a field `bh_shortcode`. When a post of this type is saved, I'd like it to add a shortcode based on the post's value of `bh_shortcode`.

If the value of `bh_shortcode` is "test", and when a [test] shortcode tag appears on a normal post type, nothing happens--[test] text is not replaced.

If I place `add_shortcode('test','save_bhour_details');` outside of the function, the [test] text is replaced.

How can I use the `add_shortcode` function inside of another function?

```
function bhour_shortcode_handler(){
    global $post,$bhourdays;

    $output='<p>this is a test</p>';

    return $output; 
}



add_action('save_post', 'save_bhour_details');

function save_bhour_details(){
    global $post, $bhourdays;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
        return;
    }

    if ( get_post_type($post) != 'bhours'){
        return;
    }

    //retrieve current values
    $current = get_post_custom();

    //if($_POST['bh_shortcode']!==$current['bh_shortcode'][0]){
        //remove current shortcode
        remove_shortcode($current['bh_shortcode'][0]);  

        //save new value
        save_bhour_field('bh_shortcode');

        //get current values
        $current = get_post_custom();

        //register new shortcode
        add_shortcode($current['bh_shortcode'][0], 'bhour_shortcode_handler');
    //}

    //register new shortcode
    add_shortcode($current['bh_shortcode'][0], 'bhour_shortcode_handler');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use as per the following code sample in your plugin.,

```
function wp_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts ) );


    //return "foo = {$foo}";
    return your_function();
}
add_shortcode( 'your-shortcode', 'wp_shortcode' );
```

I think this may help for you to get your needs.